# OpenGLES: render buffer parameters in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, opengl-es, xcode6

I make landscape-only game and use OpenGLES.

Device orientation is restricted to landscape values.

The code worked well up to updating to XCode 6. After updating to XCode 6, the following code in *PrepareFramebuffer* returns me portrait orientation on iPad mini (width = 768, height = 1024)!

```
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &width);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &hHeight);
```

I wonder if anyone knows what changed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved after adding

```
[self setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

in the end of *initWithFrame*.